# Is there a short hand for filtering a series in r

Tags: r

R noob here.  I type this syntax over and over again and I suspect there is a short hand for filtering rows within a column.

I assume #2 can be rewritten without repeating **foo** or **bar**.

Approach #1

```
foo[foo$bar > 0, 'bar']
```

Approach #2

```
foo$bar[foo$bar > 0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the larger problem you're trying to solve? You could try `with(foo, bar[bar>0])`

Comment: you can attach the data.frame by `attach(foo)` once and then you can use `bar[ bar > 0]` any number of times.

Comment: Hi Heroka, just trying to type less while also getting to know the R syntax more.  @VikramVenkat, I've never heard of attach.  Thanks!

Comment: @BGA `with` could be your friend, but generally if you're typing the same thing over and over more elegant solutions exist :)

Comment: With the data.table package you can do:  `library(data.table); dt <- as.data.table(foo); dt[bar > 0, bar]`

Comment: This is one more reason for me to start using data.table.  I tried and it worked.  I love that the column argument is now an object (bar versus 'bar').  Thanks @G.Grothendieck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons I'm in LOVE with dplyr:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

foo %>%
filter(bar > 0)
```